django/mongoengine loses connection alias after running awhile
I have a SaaS app built with django rest framework. Due to some contract requirements, each client's data has to be stored separately (on the same DocumentDB cluster but separate database). Each API ops will switch_db base on the API-Key. But after running for a while, I always get errors like: mongoengine.connection.ConnectionFailure: Connection with alias "XYZ" has not been defined
Restarting the django process will temporarily fix it until it comes again. I attempted to add a lot of try...except... to catch the ConnectionFailure exceptions, but that seems never ending battle and even that not always work. This happens almost everywhere in the workflow, read and write.
Cloud use some help around this. Maybe this is not the best way to handle multitenant connetions?
Here is an example of a get operation:
def _get_person_obj(self, person_id, close_connection=True):
    try:
        connect(host=settings.DOCDB_HOST, db=self.account.database_configuration['client_db'], alias=self.account.database_configuration['client_db'])
    except ConnectionFailure:
        disconnect(alias=self.account.database_configuration['client_db'])
        connect(host=settings.DOCDB_HOST, db=self.account.database_configuration['client_db'], alias=self.account.database_configuration['client_db'])
    try:
        with switch_db(Person, db_alias=self.account.database_configuration['client_db']) as Person_with_db_alias:
            return Person_with_db_alias.objects.get(id=person_id, api_key=self.api_key)
    except ValidationError:
        raise Http404
    except Person.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    finally:
        if close_connection:
            disconnect(alias=self.account.database_configuration['client_db'])

